# Information about a column and the data it holds?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm working with a table that has 3 different dates associated with each item in the table. I don't understand what each time is so I want to know if there's a standard place that the person who made the table may have documented what they mean.

```
RecoveryDate              |UpdateDateTime           |InitialCheckIn
2015-04-06 11:00:00.000   |2015-05-22 08:52:35.373  |2015-04-06 11:04:35.837
2015-04-02 11:07:00.000   |2015-05-06 12:52:48.923  |2015-05-01 13:03:44.977
2015-05-07 09:50:00.853   |2015-07-01 11:09:53.337  |2015-05-26 10:03:46.760
2015-05-22 09:25:00.000   |2015-06-05 08:27:43.917  |2015-05-26 09:24:47.100
2015-05-26 09:39:00.000   |2015-06-30 12:48:20.960  |2015-05-26 10:03:46.620
2015-05-29 09:57:00.000   |2015-07-02 13:53:29.277  |2015-06-03 10:21:59.687
2015-06-01 12:05:00.000   |2015-06-02 14:25:01.197  |2015-06-01 12:07:33.827
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical built in place to put this kind of metadata about columns might be in the description box when the column is selected in the table designer.

[image]

Behind the scenes this gets saved as an extended property with `MS_Description` as the property name.

It would be extremely pushing it to claim that this is "standard" or common practice though.

Comment: You were right and this was helpful for a lot of other columns that needed a little clarification. Thanks.